# MPI:Ring topology:why nodes can connect even they are not neighbors?

Tags: mpi, openmpi, hpc

Ring topology definitions:
We will assume that the nodes of a ring are connected so that node
i has neighbors i − 1 (left) and i + 1 (right), 1 ≤ i < p − 1. Nodes 0 and p − 1 are still neighbors .
When using with flat tree algorithm for broadcast,root node must send messages to all other processes . 
Why can root node connect with all of other processes when it has only two neighbors (left and right) ??

Comment: Is this about virtual topologies in MPI? Those are simply connectivity abstractions and impose no restrictions on the ability of different ranks to communicate with each other.

Comment: So what is different points when we use a topology with no using ???

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Why do we need connectivity abstractions in net work ???

Comment: I don`t think that we will have any different points between using network topology and no using network topology

Comment: This is not true in general. Virtual topologies serve both as convenience constructs and as hints to MPI that allow it to for example place the different processes in such a way that the physical connectivity matches as closely as possible the logical one.